# How to compare condition with multiple values in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to compare using if condition

```
xorg != "t8405" or "t9405" or "t7805" or "t8605" or "t8705"
```

I want to compare if xorg is not equal to all of these values on the right side then perform Y.
I am trying to figure out how can I have more smart comparison better or shell I compare xorg with one by one value?
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `in` and `ni` (**n**ot **i**n) operators are what you should look at. They test for membership (or non-membership) of a list. In this case:

```
if {$xorg ni {"t8405" "t9405" "t7805" "t8605" "t8705"}} {
    puts "it wasn't in there!"
}
```

If you've got a lot of these things and are testing frequently, you're actually better off putting the values into the keys of an array and using `info exists`:

```
foreach key {"t8405" "t9405" "t7805" "t8605" "t8705"} {
    set ary($key) 1
}

if {![info exists ary($xorg)]} {
    puts "it wasn't in there!"
}
```

It takes more setup doing it this way, but it's actually faster per test after that (especially from 8.5 onwards). The speedup is because arrays are internally implemented using fast hash tables; hash lookups are quicker than linear table scans. You can also use dictionaries (approximately `dict set` instead of `set` and `dict exists` instead of `info exists`) but the speed is similar.

The final option is to use `lsearch -sorted` if you put that list of things in order, since that switches from linear scanning to binary search. This can also be very quick and has potentially no setup cost (if you store the list sorted in the first place) but it's the option that is least clear in my experience. (The `in` operator uses a *very* simplified `lsearch` internally, but just in linear-scanning mode.)

```
# Note; I've pre-sorted this list
set items {"t7805" "t8405" "t8605" "t8705" "t9405"}

if {[lsearch -sorted -exact $items $xorg] < 0} {
    puts "it wasn't in there!"
}
```

I usually use either the membership operators (because they're easy) or `info exists` if I've got a convenient set of array keys. I often have the latter around in practice...

Comment: `in`/`ni` do comparison with each element, but easier. The other two are much quicker for big collections, but need more setup to work. (`lsort` can help with setup of the list for `lsearch -sorted`.)